# Search a Vector of Classes by a member of the Class

Tags: c++, class, search, vector, member

**Background:**

Actual Code: https://github.com/lmwunder/ElectorateProgram

I'm writing a basic program that stores election information as part of an assignment for Data Structures. It is supposed to allow users to track candidates and the votes that they've received. Users can add, edit, or remove candidates from the election information list, and the list itself can be saved or loaded. Users can also create new lists.

**Data Structures:**

Candidates are represented as follows:

```
class candidate
{
    // Data Members
    private: std::string fullName;
    private: unsigned votes;
    // Function Members
    /* Constructors and Destructors */
    /* Accessors and Mutators */
};
```

Candidates are further stored in a vector of another class:

```
class electorateList
{
    private: bool isValid;
    private: bool isModified;
    private: std::vector<candidate> electorateData;
}
```

**Question:**

When the users wants to edit or remove a candidate, I prompt them for the name of the candidate, which is a `std::string`. However, I don't exactly see how I can search the `std::vector` of candidates using only the name of the candidate. The most obvious way for me is to instantiate temporary "match" candidate object with the name data provided inside, and use that to compare against all `std::vector` members.

Ideally, I'm going for something like this:

```
// Find a candidate by name and return their position in the vector
std::vector<candidate>::iterator electorateList::find( std::string &name )
{
    std::vector<candidate>::iterator position = electorateData.end();
    // Binary search over all the vector elements
    // If candidate is matched ( found ), set the iterator to the position in the vector the match is
    /* position = // electorateData.at( whereEver );
    // Else, return the end iterator of the array
    return position;
}
```

Comment: It's not very common practise to put access specifiers (like `private`) before every member. You just need to say it once.

Comment: Use `std::lower_bound`.

Comment: You can only binary search if the elements are in order. Why not just use `std::find` or `std::find_if`?

Comment: Another portion of my project calls a sort() member after every add, edit, or delete operation that ensures all members are in ascending order. See the GitHub link in the Background section.

Comment: You should probably use a prefix tree (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: Is there a public access method for data member fullName?

Comment: I have to second chris here. Also, I took a look at the github page and what you are writing is not C++... There is way too much pointer use. (Oh and don't call sort, insert the the item into the proper place... this gets you down to O(log n) on insertion instead of O(N^2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply standard algorithm `std::find_if` provided that the class has public accessor to data member fullName. For example

For example

```
auto it = std::find_if( electorateData.begin(), electorateData.end(),
                        [&]( const candidate &c ) { return ( c.fullNameAccessor() == name ); } );

if ( it != electorateData.end() ) std::cout << "There is such candidate." << std::endl;
```

Comment: Correct answer, I'll just note that he actually does have properly sorted vector to use binary search in form of `std::lower_bound` and that his method of keeping the "is sorted" invariant is terrible. :-D

Comment: I wish there was a more flexible dialogue than just asking a single, broad question such as this.